# csh: Is there a prompt outside of $prompt?

Tags: prompt, csh

Consider this c-shell grab:

```
[<my-user>@<my-host> ~]>echo $SHELL
/bin/csh
\033]30;<my-host-name>\007\c
[<my-user>@<my-host> ~]>set | grep prompt
prompt  [%n@%m %~]%#
prompt2 %R? 
prompt3 CORRECT>%R (y|n|e|a)? 
\033]30;<my-host-name>\007\c
[<my-user>@<my-host> ~]>
\033]30;<my-host-name>\007\c
```

(the identity of the user and host is masked to protect the innocent)

I can't figure out where the `\033]30;<my-host-name>\007\c` after each line comes from, and how to make it go away.

unsetting the $prompt* variables, googleing, and grepping in the .csh* files yielded no answer.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a `precmd` alias? (run `alias | grep cmd`). It looks like that alias expects a Unix compliant `echo`. If you change it to `echo -e`, that may do something more useful.

Comment: I think that is just an escape sequence to set the hostname in a color. 033 is yellow. More than likely it is set in /etc/profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@Stéphane Chazelas](/users/22565/stephane-chazelas)'s comment led me to the answer.

The fault was indeed with the `precmd` alias:

```
precmd  echo '\033]30;<my-host-name>\007\c'
```

Unaliasing it obviously made the offending line go away, and from there diving deeper was a breeze.

From `man csh`:

> **Automatic, periodic and timed events** (+)
>
> The *beepcmd*, *cwdcmd*, *periodic*, *precmd*, *postcmd*, and *jobcmd* Special aliases can be set, respectively, to execute commands when the shell wants to ring the bell, when the working directory changes, every tperiod minutes, before each prompt, *before each command gets executed*, after each command gets executed, and when a job is started or is brought into the foreground.

Thanks.